# What keyboard layout is that

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

[image]

I got this asus mini pc with keyboard and I don't know for which country it is made for.

Comment: Portuguese ? http://www.ebay.com/itm/Keyboard-picked-from-Asus-Eee-PC-1015-PE-Portuguese-Layout-Portugal-PT-/171331704634. Why do you think it can only be for 1 country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Portuguese because of the Ç